# docker-machine - Error attempting heartbeat call to plugin server: connection is shut down

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I have fired up a docker-machine in MacOS, after I ssh into it and create some containers everything is running fine. I can see everything working as it should, even bashing into the containers is still fine there are no errors on start.

My issue comes later on as I leave myself ssh'd into the machine after some time I get this error repeating itself over and over again. This will even happen if I leave myself ssh'd in a docker container for long enough.

What is going on here?
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4HWt.png)

Temporary Solution: exit and re-ssh into the docker-machine

Comment: Just found a related Docker/Machine [github issue](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2773)

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue under the exact same circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error all of a sudden as well and it didn't go away until I restarted the virtualbox instance
`docker-machine restart default`

Comment: As my temporary solution, this is a temporary fix as well..

Yes, this does temporarily fix the issue.
No, this does not answer this as it will continue to happen

Comment: Given that it only happens when, in my case at least, after I've put my laptop to sleep, this tells me that it has something to do with the state on the VM. If I never sleep my laptop it works fine so it's pretty reproducible

Answer (score 2):

i found that there is no need to restart the docker machine. just quit the terminal window/tab and starts another one. all is good for me.

Comment: Yeah that's what i was saying in my example, there is no need to restart the machine, but this will still continue to happen if you leave youself ssh'd in